# Using different values of one variable in different functions

Tags: python, function, variables

Suppose there is this program

```
def function():
  print(variable)

def main():
  variable = "Hello"
  function()

def main_2():
  variable="Bye"
  function()

main()
main_2()
```

there's an error that `variable` is not defined

I am going to use the function `function()` a lot, and I want it to use the `variable` defined in the function `main()` for only `main()` and the variable defined in `main_2()` in only `main_2()`. How can I do that

Answer (score 1):

You define `variable` as local variable in main functions. Either you should use it as a global variable or your `function()` should take input named `variable`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is correct version of the code:

**First of all you need to call `global` to make the `local` "scope" `global`:**

Here is the snippet:

```py
def function():
    print(variable)


def main():
    global variable
    variable = "Hello"
    function()


def main_2():
    global variable
    variable = "Bye"
    function()

main()
main_2()
```

Hope so this information is useful and helpful
Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the variable to your function and use this code

```
def function(variable):
  print(variable)

def main():
  variable = "Hello"
  function(variable)

def main_2():
  variable="Bye"
  function(variable)

main()
main_2()
```